# WebView Content size

Tags: java, android, webview

I have some problems with webview content size. I need to convert full web page to a single image and tried this code

```
Bitmap screenshot;                  
screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getContentHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas c =new Canvas(screenshot);
view.draw(c);
```

where "view" is a WebView object

But the result is an image that have 1024x769 pixels. My web page is quite bigger (height is about 2000px). I've tried different ways to solve this problem, but still with zero rezult.

Answer (score 1):

I find solution.

If you have the same problem, you can add onPicture Listener to your webview, like this

```
web.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {

        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
            float temp = (float) view.getHeight();
            height = view.getContentHeight() * a;
        }

    });
```

and get all your need height and width

Answer (score 0):

For taking the picture of webview you have to enabled cache and from cache you can get it as a bitmap ,below i am mentioning the code hope will useful for you-

```
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

it is working for me just check your side,will wait for your acceptance of answer.thanks

Comment: Undortunally, it works incorrect. It display only the top of the page.